# Bootstrap jQuery and JavaScript conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that I load the header and the footer with jQuery using `load()`:

```
$(function() {
  $("#includeNav").load("navigationBar");
  $("#includeFooter").load("navigationFooter");
});
```

This was working fine until I added some javascript to pull parameters from the url (example `index.php?a=success`)

```
$(function() {
  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let myParam = new String(urlParams.get('a'));
  let compareSuccess = new String('success');   

  if (myParam.trim() === compareSuccess.trim()) {
    alert("Match");
  }

  $("#includeNav").load("navigationBar");
  $("#includeFooter").load("navigationFooter");
});
```

This will cause the Bootstrap preloader to cycle forever, not loading the page. If I put the two `load()` lines before the variable declarations, it will load the page fine, but not fire the `alert` message box?

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the console. You most likely have an error. Also, just FYI, including common static page content through AJAX is not the best idea in the world. I'd strongly suggest you include content on the server side where possible.

Comment: I am aware that it is not great for SEO etc, and I will likely hardcode it into each page down the road, it was the fastest way to get it across all pages while I work out the wording etc. 

Is there another downfall to doing it this way other than keywords and SEO etc?

Comment: SEO is one point but I was more considering the ugly FOUC you'll get as well as potentially adding a needless 2 extra requests to your server for every page load. Doesn't sound much, but it will make your website scale much worse with any decent amount of traffic as well bandwidth considerations.

Comment: Thanks Rory maybe I should just hard-code it all right now and then I wouldn't be having this issue at all!

The if statement works when I remove the Load() all together, so I know the comparison is working fine... Its just the order in which things seem to be getting called that is causing issues?